# Wget download all pages from an XML sitemap

Tags: xml, wget

I thought that this question would be a relatively easy to find a solution to but for some reason, the answers I've tried don't work.

I'm trying to simply use wget and download/mirror all of the links on my XML sitemap with the following command:

`wget --quiet http://mytestdomain.com/sitemap-pt-sale-2015-02.xml --output-document - | egrep -o "http://mytestdomain\.com[^<]+" | wget --spider -i - --wait 0`

But for some reason I just see a bunch of

`Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2015-02-16 12:49:33--  http://mytestdomain.com/sale/post1/
Reusing existing connection to mytestdomain.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.`

I'm not a CLI pro so I have no idea why it isn't actually downloading the actual page into a static.html file.

So my question is, how can I modify the command above so that it will download all of the links in the XML into static.html files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using the

```
-- spider
```

mode.

From the man pages:

> --spider
>
> When invoked with this option, Wget will behave as a Web spider, which >    means that it will not download the pages, just check that they are there.

If you'd like to guarantee the downloaded files have the .html extension use **-E**:

```
wget -E -i - --wait 0
```